# SplistDataQuery Display Multiple Lists in Repeater

Tags: development, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation

I am trying to get information from 3 lists my code looks as following i am trying to get all the list with a query by modified and display in Repeater. I Think i should write the code in `"Repeater_ItemDataBound"` and i dont really now if i need to use an Datatable or not in a Repeater because i found this code for an Grindview
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you need only to display items from lists, you can use OOTB ContentQueryWebPart.

Comment: what do u mean?

Comment: SharePoint has out of the box web parts. These web parts can be used for wide range of operations. For example, ContentQueryWebPart is a web part that can collect data from several lists and display this data by XSLT transformation. See [this article](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-designer-help/display-data-from-multiple-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part-HA010174134.aspx) for more datails.